# Rocket Trajectory (launching it vertically)

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, rocket-science

I don't have a camera that can produce a video at 240fps and i my physics experiment i am trying to find the maximum height reached by a water rocket.

My question:-

Can i use my iphone 11, that has 240fps (in slow motion). Will it produce the same video as a normal camera at 240 fps?
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about iPhones, not physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly on-topic for this site.

However, yes, 1080p at 240fps should produce some good results on the iPhone, especially at the top of the trajectory when the rocket is moving slowly. Just make sure you have an adequate scale so you can determine the height based off your video footage.

Comment: Thank you. However, i am going to attach a string to the rocket which will tell me the height. I just need to know the initial velocity, (final velocity =0 ), and the height (string). I might be able to get the second stage in the analysis. I don't think i need all the three stages for the analysis.